# Error when configuring firebase with environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I am trying to configure my Firebase project using environmental variables, and am having problems. I'm sure some of you guys/gals will be able to help me so I will get straight into the code

### .firebase.js

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
 };

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database());
const facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

export { app,base,facebookProvider };
```

### .server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const router = require('./routes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

// Define middleware here
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.use(router);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/cryptoTracker")

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` ==> Server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

### Error

@firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().

#### Furthermore

I am confused because I do have a databaseURL parameter and that environment variable IS defined in my .env file. I am not posting my .env file on here for obvious reasons but I assure you that all the variables I am calling are located inside of it.

Comment: what is the value of REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL environment variable?